# Why doesn't numpy create an array when executing a list method

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Playing around with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
l = [39, 54, 72, 46, 89, 53, 96, 64, 2, 75]
nl = np.array(l.append(3))


>> array(None, dtype=object)
```

Now, if I call on `l`, I'll get the list: `[39, 54, 72, 46, 89, 53, 96, 64, 2, 75, 3]`

**My question is, why doesn't numpy create that list as an array?**

If I do something like this:

`nl = np.array(l.extend([45]))` I get the same thing.

But, if I try to concatenate without a method:  `nl = np.array(l+[45])` it works.

What is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` and `extend` are in-place methods and return `None`.

```
print(l.append(3)) # None
print(l.extend([3])) # None
```

Answer (score 2):

The `append` function will always return `None`. You must do this in two different lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
l = [39, 54, 72, 46, 89, 53, 96, 64, 2, 75]
l.append(3)
nl = np.array(l)
```